# Schedule creation of whole machine images

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-platform

I have a VM in Google Cloud Platform that has three disks attached. I would like to schedule image creation of the whole machine, so that if it fails I can stand up a replacement with a click instead of several clicks, attaching disks, etc.

The console only provides for snapshot schedules of separate disks, however, and I can't find any gcloud commands that would create a machine image at all. Is there any way to create a scheduler for creating an image or snapshot of an entire VM, either through the console or some command I can run as a cron job?

Answer (score 1):

As per the [GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-images/create-machine-images) you can use below gcloud command to create machine image from the running instance:

```
gcloud beta compute machine-images create my-machine-image --source-instance source-instance --source-instance-zone us-central1-a
```

Now based on the above command you can create cron job schedule to create a machine image.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule Machine image using Cloud Function and Cloud Scheduler.
Refer below article
https://medium.com/@vishalbulbule/schedule-machine-images-backup-and-dr-solution-for-google-compute-vm-instances-f8b605b04f95